# Live streaming using chromecast with H.264 frames and TCP or UDP protocol

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I want to build an app where I can feed H.264 frames directly to chromecast via UDP or TCP protocol. From documentation its given that is supports H.264 video codex. Is it possible to use it directly?